# which NewRelic agent ito be installed for HP WebTours application for monitoring?

Tags: testing, performance-testing, newrelic, loadrunner, newrelic-platform

I want to monitor the HP WebTours application on my System, but i am unable to find which type of New Relic agent is required for this.
Can someone please, help me out here?

[find below snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCwLd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

What's your theory based upon your local installation of webtours?  How have you tested this theory so far?